# initialAutoRunScript in BrowserAutoPwn2

Tags: metasploit

I am trying to add some custom commands to `browserautopwn2`. When I get the session using the `initialAutoRunScript` option like this:

```
msf >     set initialautorunscript "upload /root/x.txt %temp%"
```

the commands are not executed after the session is initiated. How can I make this thing work?

P.S.: I've tried many commands, not just one and I also tried to use:

```
multi_console_command -rc ..
```

and still nothing.